# What does scratch org status of "Missing" mean?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I ran the `sfdx force:org:list --all` command. Several scratch orgs are listed with a value of `Missing` in the `STATUS` column. The `EXPIRATION DATE` is blank for all scratch orgs with the `Missing` status. I'm not sure how to interpret this status-- what are the scratch orgs missing? Or what are they missing from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Missing` status indicated that I was (somehow) disconnected from my default username org. Re-authenticating using `sfdx force:auth:web:login -s` caused the `STATUS` field to change to either `Active` or `Expired`. The `EXPIRATION DATE` was then populated as well.